# Union of node and function on node in XPath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl some webpages. I want to write an XPath query that will, within a parent `<div>`, append a couple of characters of text to any child `<a>` nodes, while extracting the text of the  div's `self` node normally. Essentially it is like a normal `descendant-or-self` or `//` query, just written with `|` and calling the `concat` function on the descendants (which, if they exist, will be `<a>` tags).

These all return a value:

1. `my_div.xpath('div[@class="my_class"]/text()).extract()`
2. `my_div.xpath('concat(\'@\', div[@class="my_class"]/a/text())').extract()`
3. `my_div.xpath('div[@class="my_class"]/text() | div[@class="my_class"]/a/text()').extract()`

However attempting to combine (1) and (2) above in the format of (3):

`my_div.xpath('div[@class="my_class"]/text() | 
concat(\'@\', div[@class="my_class"]/a/text())').extract()`

results in the following error:

`ValueError: XPath error: Invalid type in div[@class="my_class"]/text() | concat('@', div[@class="my_class"]/a/text())`

How do I get XPath to recognize the union of a node with a function called on a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it doesn't work because concat is doesn't actually return a path, and `|` is used to select multiple *paths*

> By using the | operator in an XPath expression you can select several paths.

as per http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Why not just split it into two? Generally you use [ItemLoaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with your spider. So you can simply add as many paths and/or values as you like.

```
mil = MyItemLoader(response=response)
mil.add_xpath('name', 'xpath1')
mil.add_xpath('name', 'xpath2')
mil.load_item()
# {'name': ['values_of_xpath1','values_of_xpath2']
```

If you want to preserve tree order you can try:

```
nodes = my_div.xpath('div[@class="my_class"]')
text = []
for node in nodes:
    text.append(node.xpath("text()").extract_first())
    text.append(node.xpath("a/text()").extract_first())
text = '@'.join(text)
```

You can probably simplify it with list comprehension but you get the idea: extract the nodes and iterate through nodes for both values.

Comment: I think you're right—it's an invalid type because it's not a path. ItemLoaders intuitively seem like a good idea but I want to add *intermediate* <a> tags the the item in the order they appear, not just append them.

Comment: Hmm, both of these paths share a parent node. You can try extracting parent nodes and iterate through them to find the nodes you need in right order; see my edit. Maybe that would do?

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 1.0, a [*location path*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths)  returns a [*node-set*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets). The [`concat`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-concat) function returns a [*string*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#strings). The [*union operator* `|`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets) computes the union of its operands, which must be *node-sets*.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this is what I did:

```py
item['div_text'] = []
div_nodes = definition.xpath('div[@class="my_class"]/a | div[@class="my_class"]/text()')
for n in div_nodes:
    if n.xpath('self::a'):
        item['div_text'].append("@%s" % n.xpath('text()').extract_first())
    else:
        item['div_text'].append(n.extract())
```